# Green screen of death?

Tags: 14.10, screen

on Ubuntu Workstation 14.10, 
I get a green screen (like the blue one of you know who).

I've tried different screen because I thought the first one was dead, but using ubuntu, by a certain time, I've got all freezing on a beautiful green screen.

Do someone ever seen that? What can be the cause? How to repair?

All has worked well during 3 months, and this green screen appeared a few days ago.

I've run the command: `lshw -c video`

```
*-display:0             
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: 82Q963/Q965 Integrated Graphics Controller
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 2
   bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
   version: 02
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
   configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
   resources: irq:43 memory:fea00000-feafffff memory:d0000000-dfffffff ioport:ecb8(size=8)
*-display:1 UNCLAIMED
   description: Display controller
   product: 82Q963/Q965 Integrated Graphics Controller
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 2.1
   bus info: pci@0000:00:02.1
   version: 02
   width: 32 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: memory:feb00000-febfffff`
```

Comment: It's frozen and blocked, i reboot the machine and edit the post with the output.

Comment: Ok I didn't know, sorry I'll change that

Comment: to me this sounds like a graphic card that's crashing, that's the only reason for a green screen that I can think of...

Comment: On appren en faisant!  ;-) Your problem is that you've got a 32-bit and a 64-bit driver installed for the same hardware!  Please provide the output to `uname --hardware-platform&&lsmod` so that we can delete the right one!  (answer comping up!)  In the mean time, perform a [system backup](http://askubuntu.com/questions/569679/whats-a-good-back-up-strategy-for-1-desktop-pc) You’ve been promoted to user type 4!

Comment: What setup are you using? (laptop make and model/motherboard make and model) etc

Comment: @Fabby could you please give me back the commande to set the output in english, then I don't spoil the thread with french stuff ;) Thanks

Comment: So is it a hardware problem or not?  Should we try to go down my path of deleting the 32-bit driver or did you/will you replace the hardware???  et comme réponse sur ta question: `export LANG=en_GB.UTF-8&&export LANGUAGE=en_GB:en`

Comment: @Fabby I won't try to change the hardware so I'd prefer to go down your path. I just didn't understand what to do with the second command. Should I put the result here? That's why I was asking the command to set the output in english.

Comment: Ok... it seems it's a hardware problem... tried to boot on usb live, it failed, tried to re-install Ubuntu, the GUI failed too... Thanks @Fabby for your help in any case :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "green screen" isn't Ubuntu specific.  My desktop's onboard graphics card died once, and it resulted in a green screen freezing everything.  It then subsequently hard crashed.

It sounds a lot like a dying graphics card.  The only thing you can really do is get a compatible graphics card for your system (or a replacement motherboard if it's an onboard integrated card) and see if the new graphics card being the only one running resolves the issues.

Note if the machine is a laptop, you'll have to contact the manufacturer of the laptop for parts and service.